Leetcode stacked books assignment
I encountered a problem during a coding interview last November and need some help figuring out the best approach to solve it.
I solved 100 medium in leetcode until now! but still can't come up with answer...
Problem:
You are given n types of books and an array orders representing the sequence in which the books need to be removed.
The books can only be stacked vertically, and each type of book must be stacked in pairs. Therefore orders.length is 2n. Only top of books can be removed.
The goal is to return the minimum effort required to remove the books in the exact order specified in the orders array.
Sorry for poor explanation. Below details is more helpful.
Details:
If n = 3, the books could be stacked in an order like [1,1,2,2,3,3], [2,2,3,3,1,1], [3,3,2,2,1,1], [1,1,3,3,2,2], [2,2,1,1,3,3] or [3,3,1,1,2,2].
For example, given n = 3 and orders = [3,1,2,2,1,3], if we stack the books as [2,2,1,1,3,3]: (top of books is 3.)
We can remove the first book 3 (orders[0]) immediately without any effort. The remaining stack is [2,2,1,1,3].
Next, we need to remove 1 (orders[1]). Since 1 is not at the top, we first need to remove 3, and then we can remove 1. and restock 3 again. which requires 1 effort(only for removing not considering restock). The remaining stack is [2,2,1,3].
We continue this process for the rest of the orders array, always trying to minimize the effort required to reach the next book.
Question:
How can I solve this problem to minimize the total effort?
How can I know book stacks minimizing the total effort? -> greedy?
I'm unsure how to approach this. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Priority Queue? Stack, Queue, LiknedHashMap? just Array?
The constraints is n <= 10^5 orders.length <= 2*10^5
And I thought minimum effort is 6 above example. [2,2,3,3,1,1], [3,3,2,2,1,1] and whatever has same effort, 6.
Therefore it could be quite simple.
So in my opinion, the greedy would be fitted to it. Stack book pairs in order just given orders.
if orders is [3,1,2,1,2,3] then just stack 3,3 then 3,3,1,1 then 3,3,1,1,2,2.
I can't prove it but I think it is best way. Am I right?

With the example, orders = [3,1,2,2,1,3] and stack = [2,2,1,1,3,3], we need to remove 1 and 3 to get to the first 2. Can we then remove the second 2 without restocking the 1 and 3, or does each 2 cost two removals?

It seems odd to think of removals as the “effort” rather than restocking because there are two types of removals: those we restock and those we do not.

The greedy solution of stacking your books where the books that come first in orders are placed at the top should work; that can be shown by induction on n. However, you'll have to be careful in your implementation since simply performing a simulation (explicitly removing books from the top/putting them back) to calculate the cost can have a runtime of O(n^2) depending on the arrangement of orders, which will be too slow for your supplied n.

Yes that's my problem. runtime is always $O(n^2)$.  $10^10$ is too slow. I beileve there would be O(nlogn) approach... but can't come up with that...

Can we then remove the second 2 without restocking the 1 and 3, or does each 2 cost two removals? -> No. we have to restock first and then can remove second 2. Yes it seems quite odd but I think the person who made this problem wants to make it easier.

Now I think it would be about Segment tree or Fenwick Tree. because we have to update the efforts whenever stack status is changed after removing the book. But I 'm still stuck haha

It's possible to calculate in O(N*log(N)) the effort associated with stacking the books using the greedy way. A hint is that when a book b is encountered in orders the effort needed is the current number of unique books that have been removed exactly once. Since you're using the greedy strategy there won't be any books of a particular type that weren't removed and placed before b; however, if they were removed twice already, they would not contribute any effort. Figuring out how to model this idea with the right data structure(s) would be the next step in coming up with an algorithm.

After studying Fenwick Tree and Segment tree, then getting hint from @wLui155, I solved it by Fenwick tree and HashMap. It took 1 year to solve it. wow... I realise that the basic Data structure like stack, queue, linkedList isn't enough to pass the real code assessment!
    public int books(int[] orders, int n) {
        // shelf is Fenwick Tree that starts from node 1.
        int[] shelf = new int[n + 1];
        // [bookType, index in tree]
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 1;
        for (int book : orders) {
            if (!map.containsKey(book)) {
                shelf[i] = 2;
                map.put(book, i);
                i++;
            }
            // Just for efficiency.
            if (i == n + 1) break;
        }
        // The book on top of the shelf needs no effort.
        shelf[map.get(orders[0])] = 0;
        build(shelf);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int book : orders) {
            int index = map.get(book);
            sum += query(shelf, index);
            // Removing a book has a effect on only behind for that book index.
            update(shelf, index + 1, -1);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private void build(int[] shelf) {
        for (int i = 1; i < shelf.length; i++) {
            int j = i + lsb(i);
            if (j < shelf.length) shelf[j] += shelf[i];
        }
    }

    private void update(int[] shelf, int idx, int delta) {
        while (idx < shelf.length) {
            shelf[idx] += delta;
            idx += lsb(idx);
        }
    }

    private int query(int[] shelf, int idx) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (idx > 0) {
            sum += shelf[idx];
            idx -= lsb(idx);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private int lsb(int i) {
        return i & -i;
    }
    ```

